# Assign values to cells in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have cell size of `B = 36*3969` and another cell size of `s = 36*55`. I want to assign values `s{:,1} = B{:,2048} s{:,2} = B{:,2049} s{:,3} = B{:,2049} and so on` . But I am getting the following error.

```
The right hand side of this assignment has too few values to satisfy the left hand side.

Error in group (line 22)
        s{:,a} = B{:,i};
```

Here is the section of the code.

```
win_size = [48 96];
win_stride = [8 8];
yaml_file = 'Feature000000';
YamlStruct = ReadYaml(yaml_file);
features_level_1 =  YamlStruct.features1;
total_elements =  YamlStruct.Elements;
block_hist_size =  YamlStruct.blockhistsize;
blocks_per_img = YamlStruct.blocksperimg;
B = reshape(features_level_1,36,3969);
Ax = win_size(1)/8 - 1;
Ay = win_size(2)/8 - 1;
X = 256;
Y = 256;
Ix = int64(X/8);
Iy = int64(Y/8);
Ib = (Iy * 63 + Ix) - 1;
s = cell(36,55);
a = 1;

for j= Ib:63:Ib+63*11
    for i = 1:1:5
        s{:,a} = B{:,j+i};
        a = a + 1;
    end
end
```

**EDIT**
You can find file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bh12br1cbr7b8ez/Feature000001?dl=0)

Comment: Your variable `B` is never assigned before you use it (not in the part of code you provided). Are you really sure the size of `B` is `36x3969` ?. Also, your loop over `j` is useless, `j` does not appear anywhere inside the loop statements.

Comment: I have edit my question, please check @Hoki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`B{:,i}` will return a comma separated list, i.e. it has a number of outputs equal to he number of rows of `B`. Likewise for `s{:,a}`. The assignment operator does not allow you to assign multiple outputs to multiple inputs in one go. In this case you should just be using regular parentheses:

```
s(:,a) = B(:,i);
```

Comment: I got `Index exceeds matrix dimensions.Error in group (line 24)
s(:,a) = {B{:,j+i}};` error @Dan

Comment: Then `B` does not have `j+i` columns... you are looping to too high an index. Check the values of `j` and `i` when it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

```
raw = rand(142884,1);
B = reshape(raw, 36, 3969);
C = mat2cell(B,ones(36,1),ones(3969,1));
s = cell(36,55);
```

Then to assign a column of C into s use () operator as

```
s(:,1) = C(:,2048);
```

Since I don't know what is actually in your B, I can't fully test it.  I imagine the success will depend on what's in B.

Comment: I have included the file as well.